# UID call on null and provider failing to pass on data with TypeError (type 'FirebaseUser' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, provider

I tried to reach user data to determine Admin role and pass on to Future Builder. Depending on Admin, the result will be determine if which widget will be available.

[image]

```
              floatingActionButtonLocation:
                FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
                  floatingActionButton:
                  FutureBuilder(
  future: _getProfileData(user, authNotifier),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              _isAdmin = snapshot.data['isAdmin'] ?? false;
            }
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  adminFeature(),
                  ]
                  ));
          }),
```

The widget below provides information on user.

```
    Widget adminFeature() {
    if(_isAdmin == true) {
      return 
      FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor:CompanyColors.blue[500],
                          child: const Icon(Icons.add),onPressed: () {
                              var foodNotifier = Provider.of<FoodNotifier>(context, listen: false);
                    foodNotifier.currentFood = null;
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return FoodForm(
                isUpdating: false,
              );
            }),
          );
        });
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }

  _getProfileData(User user, AuthNotifier authNotifier) async {
    final uid = await Provider.of<AuthNotifier>(context, listen: false).getCurrentUser();
  await Firestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .document(uid)
        .get().then((result) {
          user.isAdmin = result.data['isAdmin'];
    });
  }
```

[image]

Below, this is the provider. It works for all the apps, but I fail to get the user data and pass on to a widget.

```
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => AuthNotifier(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => FoodNotifier(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ThemeProvider(isLightTheme: false)),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UserxProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UsersProvider()),
        
      ],
      child: MyApp());
  }
```

Notifier is mentionned below:

```
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<String> getCurrentUID() async {
    return (await _firebaseAuth.currentUser()).uid;
  }

  // GET CURRENT USER
  Future getCurrentUser() async {
    return await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `_getProfileData` method, you should change the following:

```
await Provider.of(context, listen: false)
```

to

```
await Provider.of<UserxProvider>(context, listen: false) 
// or UsersProvider, whichever you're trying to call
```

The problem is that when you call `Provider` without specifying the model that you want (i.e., the type), it becomes `Provider.of<dynamic>` and hence you're getting that error message.

Comment: thanks Osaxma, I have this error message when I may the change: The method 'collection' isn't defined for the type 'AuthNotifier'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'collection';  I edited my codes above.